# AngularJS : Error: registerService.getRegisterResponse is not a function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

> Error: registerService.getRegisterResponse is not a function

I getting Above Error on console of the web browser. While Accessing the a method(i.e saveRegisterResponse()) from Controller (i.e RegistrationCtrl) as registerService.getRegisterResponse() Method in registerService.

Here it is clear cut code.... For Both registerCtrl(controller) & regiterService(Service)...
Am placed both Service and Controller in app.js

```
**registerCtrl(Controller).**

var app=angular.module("app.chart.ctrls",['ngSanitize']);


  app.controller("registrationCtrl",["$scope","$location","logger","registerService",function($scope,$location,registerService){

    registerService.getRegisterResponse();
}]);


**registerService(Service)**

app.factory('registerService', function () {
        var registerResponse = {};

        return {
            getRegisterResponse:function () {
             return "xyz";
            }           
        };
    });
```

While Controller is loading am getting the Error

Angularjs Error: registerService.getRegisterResponse is not a function

How to Resolve it ? Thanks in Advance ...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you did not add `logger` as one of your controller's function arguments, which makes angular look for `getRegisterResponse` in your `logger`. Change your code to something like:

```
app.controller("registrationCtrl",
["$scope","$location","logger","registerService",function($scope,$location,logger, registerService){
    registerService.getRegisterResponse();
}]);
```